# How do I write a for loop to find a factorial and only printing the final number and not the whole list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just learning through edX's course and they'd like me to write a for loop to find 5 factorial and only printing 120/the final product and not the whole list.

I've tried this:

```
mystery_int = 5

for answer in range(1,5):
    mystery_int *= answer
    print(mystery_int)
```

I'd like the result to be just "120" but the actual output is the whole list

```
5
10
30
120
```

Comment: dedent `print(mystery_int)`

Comment: Unindent `print` so it only prints once the loop is done, but that's an odd way to calculate factorial.  `mystery_int` should start as 1 and `range(1,n+1)` would be the right loop for `n!`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you are not using function to calculate the factorial. Here is what you can do, as suggested in comments:

```
mystery_int = 5

# you can skip an extra iteration of multiplying by 1 
for answer in range(2,5):
    mystery_int *= answer
print(mystery_int)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mystery_int = 10  # change this value to calculate new factorial

factorial = 1
for num in range(2, mystery_int + 1):
    factorial *= num

print('{:,}'.format(factorial))
```

As pointed out in a comment you need to move the `print()` statement outside of the for loop scope and it will print only the result after the loop ends. Also, adding a comma in the { } with format adds a thousands separator.